# SharePoint Framework SPFx & React

Tags: reactjs, sharepointframework

I'm new for SharePoint SPFx and React, got a question, the code generated by gulp below:

```
export default class HelloReactWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloReactWebPartProps> {
  public render(): void { 

    const element: React.ReactElement<IHelloReactProps> = React.createElement(
      HelloReact,
      {
        description: this.properties.description
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);

  }
```

Is there a way to create the element using JSX, not use React.ReactElement, like something below:

```
const element: React.ReactElement<IHelloReactProps> = 
        <HelloReact description={this.properties.description} />
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want the generated gulp code to output jsx?

Comment: no, I just want to manually change the generated code to the JSX code, but got syntax error.

Comment: JSX is not "legal" JavaScript syntax. that's what gulp is doing, transforming JSX to what it really is, `createElement`. you can use the online babel repl to see https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBCwQvBAeAJgSwG4QPQD4g&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works, all I need to do is rename the filename generated by the template, change the filename "HelloReactWebPart.ts" to "HelloReactWebPart.tsx".

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luUre.png)